# Update table cell value dynamically using angular6

Tags: html, css, angular6

I am working with an angular 6 application, in the HTML template I have some code as per below, just showing the table cell part of the array, also the table is built using divs.

```
<div class='table_small'>
        <div class='table_cell'>Status</div>
        <div class='table_cell'>
          <p class="status" >{{incomingData.status}}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Please note here that "data" is an array (*ngFor) and is being used in row data and there are multiple data in the table.

Now I have a situation wherein there is a button inside the table rows to cancel the particular order, when the user clicks in, a pop up/modal asks for user confirmation, if the user opts for 'Yes' it would change the status field value to "cancellation is in process" temporarily before it hits the service, once there is a successful response from the customer it would change the station to "cancelled".

I am really not sure how to do the cancellation within the table cell here, if anyone can give insight on this please do.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass the element to the function and edit its status:

```
<div class='table_small'>
    <div class='table_cell'>Status</div>
    <div class='table_cell'>
      <p class="status" >{{incomingData.status}}</p>
    </div>
    <div class='table_cell'>
      <button (click)="showCancelModal(incomingData)"> Cancel</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

And then in the component something like this:

```
showCancelModal(incomingData) {
  // logic for showing modal and retrieving user response
  if( response === 'yes') {
    incomingData.status = 'Cancel in progress';
    yourService.cancel(incomingData)
    .pipe( finally(() => incomingData.status = 'Cancelled') )
     .subscribe();
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. this works but it changes do not appear automatically, I need to click button twice to see the status has been changed. any clue ?

Comment: That's probably because of angular changes detection for ngFor, you could reassign your array to a shallow copy of itself to 'force' a re-render. You could so by adding something like this once the status is updated: yourArray = Object.assign({}, yourArray);

Comment: ok, I did the changes using  this.ref.detectChanges() and it worked, thanks for your help :)

Comment: Glad to be of help! You could mark my response as the good one if you think it's helpful ;)

Comment: in similar fashion I have to show one button in same row where I am updating my row, I need to do after successfully service hit, any guess? by default in each row this button would be hidden when records loads. but after hitting service this button in same row would get displayed.

Comment: you could add the button with a ngIf*="incomingData.status === 'Cancelled'" or something similar